# Spyder doesn't detect changes in imported python files

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, ide, spyder

I'm using Spyder 3.2.4 (Python 3.6). Spyder doesn't detect changes in imported python files. For example:

*test2.py:*

```
def func():
    return 5
```

*test1.py:*

```
import test2

a = test2.func()
print(a)
```

When I wrote those classes, and saved them (in the same working directory), and ran *test1.py* the output was `5`.

BUT when I change the function in *test2.py*, to like:

```
def func():
    return 10
```

Save it, and then run *python1.py*, I still get `5`. Only when I save, exit the IDE, and return, I will get the changed code (`10`).

This behavior is going on since I started using Spyder (few months by now), and it's super annoying. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not sure this is spyder related. You could try and use `importlib.reload`.

Comment: When I'm using Intellij IDE with the python plugin it doesn't happen, so I'm pretty sure it is Spyder related.

Comment: What I meant is that this is a python feature. If you import a module, change it in the background and then import again python will not pick up the changes. You either have to restart the interpreter or you can use `importlib.reload`.

Comment: wow thanks. It works now. I didn't know about it.
In intellij it happens automatically? answer as an answer to the question, so I'll be able to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are experiencing is a Python [feature](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#the-module-cache). Modules are initialized when first imported and kept in a cache. Each subsequent import uses the cache, so the module code is not run again.

What in most cases is an eminently reasonable economy, is rather annoying when developing. You can force python to reload a module using `importlib.reload`.

Answer (score 2):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) This is a [know issue](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/5877) and it'll fixed in our **3.2.5** version, to be released on December/2017.